# References to derived class unique_ptr in a vector

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

With:

```
std::unique_ptr<base> master_list;
std::vector<derived*> sub_list;
```

such that a subset of master_list is created by:

(1) extract from master_list using .get() 
(2) cast to derived class using dynamic_cast
(3) add casted raw pointer to sub_list
(4) Use from sub_list when needed

do you see a bug in this approach? is it rather better to:

(1) extract from master_list using .get() 
(2) add raw pointer to sub_list
(3) retrieve from sub_list when needed
(4) cast to derived class using dynamic_cast

Comment: What is the relationship between `base` and `derived`? Because if it's what you seem to suggest it is, then you either have things backwards or are doing polymorphism wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches look correct to me as long as at each `dynamic_cast` the logic correctly deals with the case that the `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr`.

In the second case, this means that when you decide you need something, it may in fact not be there (if `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr`).

Assuming the `nullptr` issues are worked out for both approaches, the best approach is going to depend upon your expected use of `sub_list[i]` for your "average" `i`.  If it is expected that most every member `sub_list` will be used more than once, it is best the way you have it (the first way).

Rationale:  `dynamic_cast` is not free.  In the first approach, you `dynamic_cast` once for each `sub_list[i]`, and then can use it multiple times.

In the second approach, you have to `dynamic_cast` once per use.  This will win in the case that you may put pointers into `sub_list` and then later decide not to use them.  If this happens a lot, you can avoid ever having to `dynamic_cast` for those pointers moved but not used.

If you always use each pointer put into `sub_list` exactly once, the two approaches should be identical in performance (and correctness).